# Is there a way to exclude node_modules from webpack on a global levle?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, node-modules

I have simple config for demonstration that excludes node modules from js and jsx file, but can't find a solution to exclude node_modules, globally so I don't need to always specify this exclude in every loader

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.js")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    publicPath: "/",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ["babel-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: ["babel-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist")]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/index.html") }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
  ]
};
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm on webpack 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ["babel-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/ },
```